# Batch File Windows

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

```
P1=c:\users\a\
P2=c:\users\b\
Q1=c:\users\c\
Q2=c:\users\d\
olderthan=7
```

P1 and P2 are source directory
Q1 and Q2 are destination directory

The Purpose behind this logic is to look for the files which was older than 7 days from P1 and P2 directroy. Those old files should be copy into Q1 and Q2 and delete it from P1 and p2.

I have done it for P1 to Q1 by using below logic:

```
FORFILES -p %P1% /d -%olderthan% -m *.%extension% -c "CMD /C XCOPY %P1%\@FILE %Q1%"
FORFILES -p %P1% /d -%olderthan% -m *.%extension% -c "CMD /C if exist %Q1%\@FILE del %P1%\@FILE /Q & echo @FILE Deleted." >> %loglocation%
```

But how to do it for P1 to Q1 as well as P2 to Q2 using for loop or any other logic?

Comment: Using pure CMD batch file would require parsing each dates from a `DIR` command in a `FOR` command loop. If you're concerned about performance, you might want to use *VBScript* instead.

Comment: I need CMD batch file only. Don't want VB Script........

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any single loop that can process multiple source and destination pairs. You need to apply the same logic to each pair individually. Perhaps a subroutine will simplify things.

You can simplify your logic by replacing the XCOPY and DEL commands with a single MOVE command.

The FORFILES /D option uses "less than or equal" logic, not "less than". If you truly want to move folders that are older than 7 days then you need to use a value of 8 instead.

I've added quotes around the paths just in case you ever get a path containing spaces. The quotes need to be doubled up inside the command string.

I've made the routine more flexible by using a file mask parameter instead of an extension parameter.

```
@echo off
call :moveOldFiles c:\users\a *.txt 7 c:\users\c >>mylog.log
call :moveOldFiles c:\users\b *.txt 7 c:\users\d >>mylog.log
exit /b

:moveOldFiles  sourceDir  extension  minAgeInDays  destinationDir
forfiles /p "%~f1" /m %2 /d -%3 -c "cmd /c move /y @path ""%~f4\"" && echo @path moved to "%~f4"""
exit /b
```

You really should look into using ROBOCOPY instead of FORFILES. It should perform better and it is extremely flexible. Just as with FORFILES, you would need to call ROBOCOPY once for each source/destination pair.

Comment: EDIT - Used `&&` instead of `&` so message is only output if move was successful

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.After moving the files into folder c and d. I want to zip the files. How to make this one? Zip file name should be current date and year. Thanks in advance.